# trying to understand how to add items in array?

Tags: c, data-structures

to understand the data structure assume a linked list of nodes where each node has an array called bucked which can store some strings.

```
struct NODE
{
   char *bucket[BUCKET_SIZE]; // an array of strings
   int count;                 // number of items in the array
   Node *next;
};
```

and to insert in this list the prototype of function is:

```
insert( List *list, char *new_string );
```

I am trying to understand what this means. I have a bucket (an array) of some size (e.g.: 20) which is inside a struct (node) of a linked list.

"As you add values to the list, they can be inserted into an existing bucket if there is room, using a regular ordered array insertion (shuffling items down)."

These are two ways which I think would work. Please let me know which one to implement.
bucket[8]

**Type a:**

```
1 insert "o".

bucket[0]="o";


2 insert "one"

bucket[0]="o"

bucket[1]="one"


3 insert "two"

bucket[0]= "0"

bucket[1]="one"

bucket[2]="two"


bucket[8]
```

**Type b:**

```
1 insert "o"

bucket[0]="o";


2 insert "one"

bucket[0]="one"

bucket[1]="o"


3 insert "two"

bucket[0]= "two"

bucket[1]="one"

bucket[2]="0"
```

or i am getting it completely wrong there is something else which its trying to tell me.

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown yes it is C language

Comment: Define your example struct and the input explicitly first.

Comment: Both way is valid, just differ in order. And when count > BUCKET_SIZE, create a new node inside linked list.

Comment: If your concern is what is this data structure do: this is just a typical C dynamic array implemention. When used up every BUCKET_SIZE space, you just allocate another BUCKET_SIZE space, and linked with previous one.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on how you interpret "regular ordered array insertion" and "shuffling items down".

By "ordered array insertion", does it mean "sorted array insertion"?  If it does, neither of your suggestions would work.  Rather, you'd want an insertion that inserts the value correctly  within the array at its sorted position.  If it does not, then either of your suggestions would work (but first, let's consider the next phrase).

By "shuffling items down", does it mean "keep pushing items down"?  If it does, you'd want Type b.  If it doesn't, you'd want Type a.

Since this doesn't seem like a standard library requirement or anything, you probably would have better luck asking the source of your requirements.

Also, as moeCake also pointed out, you'll have to handle the case when count > BUCKET_SIZE as well.